# rails json format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, jquery

i'm trying to render a json string in response to a request like following:

```
def check_progress
  if request.xhr?
    render :json=>"{'bytes_expected': #{session[:size]}, 'bytes_recieved': #{session[:size]}, 'last_seq': 0}".to_json
  end
end
```

but in my js code :

```
$.getScript('contacts/check_progress', function(data){
    console.log(data.bytes_recieved)
    console.log(data.bytes_expected)
    d.renderProgress(data);
});
```

I get undefined in response to `data.bytes_recieved` and `data.bytes_expected`.

what's wrong in my rails code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Think your main problem might be that your returning a string which looks like json and is not actually a json hash.

in your render statement you are hand formatting the json as a string... which is fine until you call to_json on it.

to_json is suspose to be passed a hash not a string.

You could try removing the .to_json at the end of your render statement:

```
render :json=>"{'bytes_expected': #{session[:size]}, 'bytes_recieved': #{session[:size]}, 'last_seq': 0}"
```

or create a ruby hash then convert it to json:

```
@ruby_hash = {
  :bytes_expected => session[:size],
  :bytes_recieved => session[:size],
  :last_seq => 0
}

render :json=> @ruby_hash.to_json
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`$.getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) method of jQuery inserts a `<script>` node to the `<head>` of your HTML document.

With that method your browser won't send the `X-Requested-With` HTTP header to the server. Because it will be a simple HTTP request not an AJAX one. And your browser is waiting a javascript in the response not a JSON data.

In the jQuery documentation of the `$.getScript` method is somewhat misleading because it says `data` in the callback function of the method signature, but it won't give you any data in the callback function, because your browser simply executes the javascript there is no actual payload with this request.

There is to possible solutions:

- If you need to load data from cross-domain, then try to remove the `request.xhr?` condition an use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) method and callback
- if it's not a cross-domain situation, simply load with a [$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) response and don't touch the condition

*Update*: and I have not seen it but @Barlow pointed it out you need to fix your json generation code in your rails app as he says.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code to:

```
def check_progress
  if request.xhr?
    render :json => {'bytes_expected' => session[:size], 
                     'bytes_recieved' => session[:size], 
                     'last_seq' => 0}
  end
end
```

as `render :json` will do the conversion of hash into JSON object for you. I dont know if this will solve the problem.